# Is this a valid shortcut for limits of rational polynomialls at infinity?

Tags: calculus, education

In Calculus 1, students are taught to find limits of rational polynomials at infinity by dividing by the polynomial of the highest power in the denominator. However, some students want to evaluate the coefficients whenever the numerator and denominator have the same power. Let me explain what I mean by example.

Let
$$f(x) = \frac{5x^2+9x+10}{2x^2+x}.$$
Then to evaluate $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$, of course, the students should divide everything by $x^2$ and see that the limit goes to $\frac{5}{2}$. However, some students simply say "The power is the same on the top and bottom so this becomes $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}\frac{5x^2}{2x^2} = \frac{5}{2}$.

This seems like it may not be a valid shortcut, however, if a student asked me why they could not do it, I do not know if I could come up with a good answer. Is there a more complex example where this line of thinking would not hold up?

Comment: What makes you believe that this fails?  Also, this seems like it might be more of a math ed question than a pure math question.  The approach you suggest is typically the one taught early in a class, when few tools have been developed.  By the time L'Hospital is introduced, however, there is a much easier way to see what is going on.

Comment: In fact, asymptotic analysis makes it straightforward to formalize the argument: $5x^2 + 9x + 10 \sim 5x^2$ as $x\to\infty$, meaning formally that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{5^2 + 9x + 10}{5x^2} = 1$, and similarly $2x^2 + x \sim 2x^2$ as $x\to \infty$.  etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I considered posting this in the math education stack exchange but thought it might be more appropriate here since my question had to do with the legitimacy of the technique itself rather than the education. The asymptotic argument makes sense. I was simply concerned that the student was oversimplifying the problem and there may be some bizarre case in which that line of logic would not hold up.

Comment: Again, I don't understand what you mean by the "legitimacy of the technique".  Personally, if *grading* work, I would not give full marks to a student in my first semester calculus class if they did as you describe, because the tools for *justifying* that computation have not been introduced yet.  In that context, the approach is not "legitimate", even if it leads to the correct answer.  But in the second semester, we introduce ideas like comparative rates of growth, asymptotic analysis, and L'Hospital's rule, at which point the student *can* justify the result.   There, it's "legitimate".